# Static var on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use static vars on AppDelegate on Swift so I can set/get values for all the viewControllers

AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
 struct Static {
        static var userId: String?
    }
```

Getting:

```
var userGuid: String = AppDelegate.Static.userId!
```

Setting:

```
AppDelegate.Static.userId = "123456"
```

However somehow my static var is always passing nil

What could be happening ? Thx

Comment: Are you sure the code to set the user ID is being executed before the ID is accessed? Where does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Would it make a bit clear to have a dedicated class for your user session info instead?

Example (assuming Swift 2.0 is being used)

```
class SessionInfo  {
    var userId:String?
    static let sharedInstance = SessionInfo()
}
```

Then

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    SessionInfo.sharedInstance.userId = "foobar"
    return true
}
```

And in another view

```
 @IBOutlet weak var labelTop: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        labelTop.text = SessionInfo.sharedInstance.userId
    }
```